# Unit Test for XML code Changes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, magento-community, phpunit

We can run Unit test cases for PHP classes in Magento 2 using **phpUnit**.

I would like to know how to configure and run Unit test cases for XML files like **cms_block_form.xml** or any other XML files ?

Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.